# Cocos2dx-v3. Does “preloadEffect in SimpleAudioEngine” cache duplicates?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

Will calling

```
SimpleAudioEngine::getInstance()->preloadEffect("sound.mp3");
```

multiple times lead to duplicating cache? and lead to taking up more memory?